# Neo4J HA on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, neo4j, tomcat8

Or any web application server.

I have a master Neo4J server stood up on a server in AWS.

I have a web application using Embedded Neo4J and I want it to cluster with the Neo4J server.

I have my set up code structured like this:

```
static class ZeusHADatabaseFactory extends HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory {    

    public GraphDatabaseService newEmbeddedDatabase(String path) {

        System.out.println("New Highly Available Database! " + SystemGlobals.getProperties().getProperty("neo4j.ha.initial_hosts"));
//10.0.0.185:5001

        if(graphDB != null){
            return graphDB;
        }else{
            graphDB = super.newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(path)
                    .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.keep_logical_logs, "false")
                    .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.allow_store_upgrade, "true")
                    .setConfig("ha.server_id", "2")
                    .setConfig("ha.inital_hosts", (String)SystemGlobals.getProperties().getProperty("neo4j.ha.initial_hosts"))
                    .newGraphDatabase();   
            graphDB.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().setEnabled(true);
            graphDB.index().getRelationshipAutoIndexer().setEnabled(true);          

            registerShutdownHook(graphDB);


            return graphDB;
        }


    }       

}
```

But I get errors like this:

```
18-Oct-2015 12:01:40.280 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.neo4j.helpers.Format.ThreadLocalFormat] (value [org.neo4j.helpers.Format$ThreadLocalFormat@6d43962d]) and a value of type [java.text.SimpleDateFormat] (value [java.text.SimpleDateFormat@3dee4855]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

18-Oct-2015 12:01:40.286 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.CursorPool.MuninnReadPageCursorThreadLocal] (value [org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.CursorPool$MuninnReadPageCursorThreadLocal@421bc39]) and a value of type [org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnReadPageCursor] (value [org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnReadPageCursor@75a2b06e]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

18-Oct-2015 12:01:40.287 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.CursorPool.MuninnWritePageCursorThreadLocal] (value [org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.CursorPool$MuninnWritePageCursorThreadLocal@612ffdbc]) and a value of type [org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnWritePageCursor] (value [org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnWritePageCursor@57e92367]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Is my configuration correct?

UPDATE:  I got this working on my local machine (using Resin Java EE server) but when I deploy to Tomcat on AWS I still get the same error messages.

Comment: Are you registering a shutdown hook somewhere? that might be the problem.

Comment: Turns out I had a typo in ha.inital_host, it was spelled wrong.  I got it working on my local machine, still not on Elastic Beanstalk though.  I did have an issue with my code trying to set schema indexes which it slapped me once I transitioned to HA mode, but I had a work around for that.  But I did have an issue with Neo4j spatial when a new empty instance tries to join the cluster, but I will post that in a separate question.

Comment: I am registering a shutdown hook.  It does work when using standard Embedded, and works when I use resin on my local machine.  Not sure if it's a factor in the error on Tomcat on AWS